# Django Custom Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Currently I have an app with a save method in its models.py . So I would like to change this so the models does not do the save() method, but rather have a separate view that will do this in die admin site.

Can you please direct me in the correct direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Override `save_model` in your `ModelAdmin` class. The (bare) original is in `django.contrib.admin.options`.

Comment: Please explain. Im still new to django

Comment: You first. What are you trying to do? Why? What have you tried already? What about my answer is not clear?

Comment: Currently I have a save function in my Models. Now I would like to remove that save function out of the models. Perhaps to a admin_view.py file or someting. What I gather from what you are saying , I should do the save in the admin.py file right?